# how to model 1 known property and an unknown property name with a known type in typescript

Tags: typescript

how do I model having 1 known property and 1 property where I know the type butg I do not know the property name.

I think it should be a recursive type but I am not entirely sure how to do this in typescript.

So I have this type of arrangement:

```
export const hierarchy: Hierarchy = {
  location: {
    name: "location",
    regions: [
      {
        name: "West Coast",
        states: [
          {
            name: "California",
            cities: [
              { name: "San Diego", sites: [{name: "site 1"},
              { name: "Los Angeles" },
              { name: "San Jose" },
            ],
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

So each object has a name field and an array of the same type and any level deep.

Here is my naive attempt which obviously does not work:

```
export interface Graph<T> {
  name: string;
  [key: string]: Graph[]
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do that, because `key` might be `"name"`.

Comment: i can’t use exclude?

Comment: TypeScript does not support types like "every possible string except one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently have a way to [directly express](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) "all `string`s except for `'name'`" as a type at all, let alone as a [key type of an index signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797) or a mapped type.  So you *want* to say something like:

```
// this is not valid TypeScript (yet?)
interface Graph { 
  name: string, 
  [k: string & not "name"]: Array<Graph> 
}
```

but you can't.  Maybe this will happen eventually, but for now it is just a dream.

---

What you *can* do is express `Graph` as a *constraint* on an object type, using [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types, as well as [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  The idea is, instead of `Graph`, you have a generic type alias `VerifyGraph<T>`, which takes as a parameter `T` a candidate type you hope is a valid `Graph`.  If `T` *is* a valid `Graph`, then `VerifyGraph<T>` will be the same as `T`.  Otherwise, `VerifyGraph<T>` will be changed into a valid `Graph` by fixing whatever property isn't correct.  Finally, you make a generic helper function `asGraph<T>()` that takes an argument of type `T & VerifyGraph<T>`.  The compiler will infer the type `T` as the type of the argument, and then it will check `VerifyGraph<T>` to make sure it also conforms.  If it does, great, since `T & VerifyGraph<T>` will just be `T & T` or `T`.  If not, you'll get an error message, since `T & VerifyGraph<T>` is not `T`.

Also, since you seem to be creating a `Hierarchy` which holds a `Graph`, we can express that as a generic type also with its own helper function:

```
type VerifyGraph<T> = T extends { name: string }
    ? { [K in keyof T]:
        K extends "name" ? string :
        T[K] extends Array<infer E> ? Array<VerifyGraph<E>> :
        Array<{ name: string }>
    } : { name: string }

const asGraph = <T>(x: T & VerifyGraph<T>): T => x;

interface Hierarchy<T> {
    location: T & VerifyGraph<T>
}

const asHierarchy = <T>(x: Hierarchy<T>): Hierarchy<T> => x;
```

Here it is working:

```
// okay
const hierarchy = asHierarchy({
    location: {
        name: "location",
        regions: [
            {
                name: "West Coast",
                states: [
                    {
                        name: "California",
                        cities: [
                            {
                                name: "San Diego",
                                sites: [
                                    { name: "site 1" },
                                    { name: "Los Angeles" },
                                    { name: "San Jose" },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

and here are some errors:

```
const badHierarchy1 = asHierarchy({
    location: {
        name: "Okay",
        notAnArray: 123 // error!
//      ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }[]'.    
    }
})

const badHierarchy2 = asHierarchy({
    location: { // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~ <-- Property 'name' is missing in type '{ noName: never[]; }'
        noName: []
    }
})

const badHierarchy3 = asHierarchy({
    location: {
        name: "level1",
        stuff: [
            {
                name: "level2",
                deeperNotAnArray: "oopsie"; // error!
//              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }[]'.
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

So that all behaves as desired, I think.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20VerifyGraph%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20K%20extends%20%22name%22%20%3F%20string%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20Array%3Cinfer%20E%3E%20%3F%20Array%3CVerifyGraph%3CE%3E%3E%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Array%3C%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20asGraph%20%3D%20%3CH%3E(x%3A%20H%20%26%20VerifyGraph%3CH%3E)%3A%20H%20%3D%3E%20x%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Hierarchy%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20T%20%26%20VerifyGraph%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20asHierarchy%20%3D%20%3CH%3E(x%3A%20Hierarchy%3CH%3E)%3A%20Hierarchy%3CH%3E%20%3D%3E%20x%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20hierarchy%20%3D%20asHierarchy(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22location%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20regions%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22West%20Coast%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20states%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22California%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cities%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22San%20Diego%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sites%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22site%201%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Los%20Angeles%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22San%20Jose%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20badHierarchy1%20%3D%20asHierarchy(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Okay%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20notAnArray%3A%20123%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20~~~~~~~~~~%20%3C--%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%5B%5D'.%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20badHierarchy2%20%3D%20asHierarchy(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20~~~~~~~~%20%3C--%20Property%20'name'%20is%20missing%20in%20type%20'%7B%20noName%3A%20never%5B%5D%3B%20%7D'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20noName%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20badHierarchy3%20%3D%20asHierarchy(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22level1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stuff%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22level2%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20deeperNotAnArray%3A%20%22oopsie%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%20%3C--%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%5B%5D'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

---

This might be more complicated than you want to use in your code.  The big downside here is that `Graph` is no longer a concrete type, but a generic type, so every function and type that deals with it needs to add a generic parameter.  So possibly you'd only want to put this restriction on a function called by a user to pass something in, and then inside your libraries that deal with it you'd just use a looser type like

```
interface LooseGraph {
   name: string,
   [k: string]: string | Array<LooseGraph>
}
```

instead.  Every valid `T & Graph<T>` is assignable to `LooseGraph`, but not vice versa, so you'd probably have to do some assertions in your libraries.  But that's the best I think you can currently do with TypeScript.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!