# Partial<T>, but extended with methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create generic type (with parameter `T`), that allows following behavior:

- If `K` is key of `T` allow value type `T[K] | ((params?: Partial<T>) => string)`
- If `K` is not key of `T`, allow value type `((params?: Partial<T>) => string)`

I've tried this code:

```
type PartialOrFunction<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] | ((params?: Partial<T>) => string)
} & {
  [K: string]: ((params?: Partial<T>) => string);
};
```

But it rejects `Partial<T>` (`TS2345`).

Then I've tried this code:

```
type PartialOrFunction<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] | ((params?: Partial<T>) => string)
} & {
  [K: string]: ((params?: Partial<T>) => string) | any;
};
```

But it doesn't perform type checking on extraneous properties (because it allows `any`).

Comment: What version of typescript are you on? Your first example seems to work on Typescript Playground for me.

Comment: There's no way to express the type "`K` is not a key of `T`" directly as a concrete type.  That would require [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) which are not part of the language yet.  You can respresent something like `VerifyPartialOrFunction<T, U>` where `U` is a *candidate* type conforming to `PartialOrFunction<T>`, and use it in a helper function, as in [this case with a different constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260529/how-to-model-1-known-property-and-an-unknown-property-name-with-a-known-type-in/56263831#56263831).

Comment: It might be of use to you, but it's definitely more complicated (you'd have to carry around an extra generic parameter when you use the type).  If you're interested I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want the generic-constraint version of `PartialOrFunction` I mentioned in the comments, here it is.

Your `PartialOrFunction<T>` is a specific case of something I'd like to call `DefaultProperty<T, D>` which takes an object type `T` with no index signature and adds a "default" property of type `D`.  This is different from a string index signature, which would require that all properties in `T` be assignable to `D`.  But as you've seen, TypeScript does not support that.

In order to do that you'd need to be able to [negate types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) to exclude `keyof T` from `string`, and you'd need to be able to use such negated types as [the key type of an index signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797).  Right now you can't do either.  So for `DefaultProperty<T, D>` you *want* to say something like:

```
// this is not valid TypeScript (yet?)
type DefaultProperty<T, D> = T & { [k: string & not keyof T]: D }
```

[but you can't](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317#issuecomment-487643147).  The closest you could get would be the

```
type MakeshiftDefaultProperty<T, D> = T & {[k: string]: D | T[keyof T]}
```

but this is too wide, as it allows unwanted things in your extra properties.  If you can handle that, then great.  Otherwise, read on:

So what you *can* do, is to make a type `VerifyDefaultProperty<T, D, C>` which takes a *candidate* type `C` and return a new type which would be like `DefaultProperty<T, D>`.  If `C` is assignable to `VerifyDefaultProperty<T, D, C>`, then `C` is a valid `DefaultProperty<T, D>`.  If `C` is *not* assignable to `VerifyDefaultProperty<T, D, C>`, then the places where they differ are the places in `C` that are a problem.

```
// caveat: T should probably not already have an index signature
type VerifyDefaultProperty<T extends object, D, C> =
    { [K in keyof C]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : D }
```

For example:

```
interface T {x: number, y: string};
type D = boolean;
interface CGood {x: 0, y: "y", z: true};
type VGood = VerifyDefaultProperty<T, D, CGood>;
// type VGood = {x: number, y: string, z: boolean}
// CGood is assignable to VGood: yay!
interface CBad {x: 0, y: "y", z: true, oops: 123};
type VBad = VerifyDefaultProperty<T, D, CBad>;
// type VBad = {x: number, y: string, z: boolean, oops: boolean}
// CBad is *not* assignable to VBad: boo!
// specifically, CBad['oops'] is not assignable to boolean
```

Now, since TypeScript doesn't support `DefaultProperty<T, D>`, it also doesn't support `PartialOrFunction`.  But we can take `VerifyDefaultProperty<T, D, C>` and make a `VerifyPartialOrFunction<T, C>` from it, which acts the same way.  That is, `C` is assignable to `VerifyPartialOrFunction<T, C>` if and only if `C` would be a valid `PartialOrFunction`, and any deviation can be used in an error message:

```
type VerifyPartialOrFunction<T, C> = VerifyDefaultProperty<
    { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] | ((params?: Partial<T>) => string) },
    ((params?: Partial<T>) => string),
    C
>;
```

Finally we introduce a helper function that takes a parameter of type `C` and returns it, but throws a compile-time error if `C` is not a valid `VerifyPartialOrFunction<T, D, C>`.  Note that this function must be [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), because you want to pass in the type `T` manually and have the type `C` inferred automatically, but TypeScript doesn't support [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) as of TS3.5.  So we need to break it into two functions:

```
const verifyPartialOrFunction = <T>() =>
    <C>(x: C & VerifyPartialOrFunction<T, C>): C =>
        x;
```

And now, let's test it:

```
// Tests
interface Foo {
    a: string,
    b: number,
    c: boolean
}

const goodPartialOrFunctionFoo = verifyPartialOrFunction<Foo>()({
    a: (x?: Partial<Foo>) => "a",
    b: 1,
    w: () => "w"
}); // okay

const badPartialOrFunctionFoo = verifyPartialOrFunction<Foo>()({
    a: 1, // error!
    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 
    // 'number & ((params?: Partial<Foo> | undefined) => string)'.
    b: (x: string) => "oops", // error!
    // Type '(x: string) => string' is not assignable to type 
    // '((x: string) => string) & 
    //  (number) | ((params?: Partial<Foo> | undefined) => string))'.
    w: "w"; // error!
    //  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 
    // 'string & (params?: Partial<Foo> | undefined) => string'.
})
```

That looks like the behavior you want.

---

So that's good as far as it goes.  As you can see, it drags a lot of type system fudging around with it, and every value/function/type that depends on `PartialOrFunction` is now going to have to deal with an extra generic type parameter.  This can be tedious, so I generally only recommend this kind of work on exposed APIs that users will call to use your library. Inside your library you should just carefully use the widened types like

```
type MakeshiftPartialOrFunction<T> = Partial<T> & { [k: string]: 
  T[keyof T] | undefined | ((params?: Partial<T>) => string)
}
```

and employ [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) when you know something is safe but the compiler doesn't.

---

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEBUE8AcFMGUDGAnAltALqAJge1gM4B2A5FogK7LKxEYA2koBF00uyWAIrAGYCGFehgAKyXHE6QAPOAA0oLgD4AUCFAB3ABapEW0KgKgMW2M34BbM-yPhQsAB6JYmY1v5Z+RJhSIE4iKi8qLDYoNDikhghBGpg-DSg-PT0uBqhxrig7gBuZiZm2HyCwsYwZlwAdKCgAEqoAOZaWERpSSmgkLgUcaCIXjhZhsy4ViaoRA2g9KgA1mZ2AGSgAN4A2rMAXMwYaJMAuttcoAA+EBuwXbwQ+wC+vdq6+sMYuFkaqEWVcb0AarBoXiQHgCISiSIAjAyeSKBQAYSUxn48yM-D6Xmwnw8+XKoDhvQxoBoGCofiSoAsuExwQyeWQBFQuCIoFw11QWEeegMsXUNgZDSI-AARvR8lkQSVwRJIdCFMpqnjuUkCPzBSKxaA-gCgsDimCxNKpKBZHL4YigkkiGEmYwDNd8eoNN16GEhdYVY01aLMoo9cIDVFZYpVCBegAxDj2ByWaCiza9CYYAECZwQVYObZECgWN3IBSQbYEXYTBq3ADcvShcEUoAAvKAhW9RV4K+pE8n+Km4entgAGfPbABEkEHCgAXttdhRYPd1P9AbrQf6IVITVw5AjQAA-HugLM5gEDnZ7Brj7aN3DNoizsDd4Z8z3C72vUDznUS-UrqEm2F4xGa0N1H6PIPG2OwCC0Z0wlaLBcmsZkJiKBxmEfEkaBUKszDfIEP2XQ1vzsRwkytIxcCFAArWBEAwU0-zrFQahqFZQDWABpAxmXmK48UOUB2KI2hsCMLjWTTAB+c5WP2UAjlAe5eigOAkDQVw8EIUhyCoGg6FtFg2A4LARASaJkgAeWQMNfGoxkiFkJRvkAsBsMgIzOFQMyLKs6ImR-TcMGRQhyUwtNCX6K0sSTStcThBU71RD0BSfDVnNckz6HMyyiGsnyYQRBNrkJG0mAtbsnSEV13VVJKfVS9z0s8rLvNs8AQ2ABSdCMCgCEC5zcKlQMf3XOiMNxFLjLqjKvJs3zEXrXq-X6mVpAYxjmLYjjQBE65wH2MSwLY6SzgACiO6AEksAg9tAWrkjsgBKOtESLE8HtuOQVpqE6zuQC6rpu+h7se48Szu97GLxFQlArFRejhLSQjCUx6EkUBeCmpkkVmEsgtxb7LFgJNkAgXoAEksGJUlUQQoo6HZJg0camy3A8IkCcpgwMCMCZoAoGjeiFXm3HEDQqfsahIwtAoOJ5rBhl6GDyRyZJPmu8aPMy7LmTsn51AAOVwJNtgZzWlUoagEYbKjBG68I1foMpqzxsYAQTIheABWhUzUowFccQwMEqQPOm6TQvCwF9-ConU0wF2W3YBCH1AId4zCIWAMgwJ1pn4SAAVI65jaalRECZItQDpHV-smxmMfrOyjoe2tVHB6QESOjNFWWMa3PV9HmrNO7tm7JuPvB0AHGh9RwEITmVHbZAUzMCMshWUf+ELYtJjBxihUzbNc23mpEHPJtYC8FR5JLvwsAaN5sCrhrNeXuty+1IEH41prpGXpQG6O1fwbr1AO3P6dtv5vCUI3REg5+CjlHrvUAABGQ+mhtgNyBoODQg4L53TLKAdQuBZg5xhlfMuQp+D3zttXJ+bwX4V3flQx+X8f5-wAYxIByD8FgABOIZAABCUeU9cQkH3LmEgSoFYPkSuqH0wVBFgBEfvBOywvrnQsJdbY-1wG4ERGcXwRRghp2wFA4Gkw7okG+ODBB7cN4vQwW8aABBRxcLFrwgR4MhHVhIDY0xDQTHPRLOI4YkiEpeg1HIjxCiTodwCWYoGsS-GgGWPIz6oiAQPWOqdNRGjVY9wBj-U4oB9F8AmKEfxm8-HmMsYxDQQ4sF4PUDwjg7jGLqAgMIhJQSfYG2VFVGRL4ImtIUQkpJwCnY5K0QUvRVoSlGPKSeCxOCVBAA)

Hope that helps; good luck!